# What type of tree is this? It is approximately 12 feet tall

Tags: identification, trees

Can anyone tell me what type of tree this is? It is approximately 12 feet tall and has small round berries.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a Toyon tree, botanical name is Heteromeles arbutifolia.

Answer (score 0):

I want to say that this is a naseberry aka spodilla tree, based off of having one in my garden that looks similar, but that's only if the berries are yellow/orange.

Comment: The berries turn red and remain small and don't turn into fruit like the Sapodilla trees have